# Im trying to attach an image to my email sender written python

Tags: python, email-attachments

Here is my code

```
import sys
import smtplib
import imghdr
from  email.message import EmailMessage
from tkfilebrowser import askopenfilename
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.encoders import encode_base64
from email import encoders

def send():
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = body
    msg['From'] = 'sender@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'receiver@gmail.com'
```

it worked well until  i added this below to attach an image

```
    with open('DSC_0020.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        mime =  MIMEBase('image', 'jpg', filename="DSC_0020.jpg")
        mime.add_header('Content-Dispotion', 'attachment', filename="DSC_0020.jpg")
        mime.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', '0')
        mime.add_header('Content-ID', '<0>')
        mime.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(mime)
        mime.attach(mime)
                      
    msg.set_content('This is a plain text email')
    msg.add_alternative("""\
        <DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1 style="color:gray;"> This is an HTML Email! </h1>
                <img src="body">
            </body>
        </html>
        """, subtype='html')

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login('sender51@gmail.com', 'password')
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

here is the error i get can someone tell me what im doing wrong

File "C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\message.py", line 210, in attach
raise TypeError("Attach is not valid on a message with a"
TypeError: Attach is not valid on a message with a non-multipart payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of the email message should be of type `MIMEMUltipart` and then text content should be of type `MIMEText` as follows:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
# and, of course, other imports

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative') # to support alternatives
msg['Subject'] = body
msg['From'] = 'sender@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@gmail.com'

with open('DSC_0020.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    mime =  MIMEBase('image', 'jpg', filename="DSC_0020.jpg")
    mime.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="DSC_0020.jpg") # corrected header
    mime.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', '0')
    mime.add_header('Content-ID', '<0>')
    mime.set_payload(f.read())
    encode_base64(mime) # improved statement (you can now get rid of following import: from email import encoders)
    msg.attach(mime) # corrected statement

# Attach the plain text as first alternative
msg.attach(MIMEText('This is a plain text email', 'plain'))
# Attach html text as second alternative
msg.attach(MIMEText("""\
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1 style="color:gray;"> This is an HTML Email! </h1>
            <img src="body">
        </body>
    </html>
    """, 'html'))
```

You had some errors in your file processing block, which I tried to correct. There may have been others I did not catch.

Comment: Sorry forgot about that